# Can virtual memory be used to allocate more memory for WSL2?

Tags: memory, wsl2, virtual-memory

I'm running WSL2 on a laptop with 16BG RAM. Working on a project in Node which in local development when run takes as much as 7GB of memory which is almost all of the allowed 50% and this causes webpack to kill of the app multiple times. Memory usage in Task Manager goes constantly over 90%.

Would manually increasing page size and allocating extra memory to WSL2 be a feasible solution? I'm not sure if my company's IT would be able to physically upgrade internals to 32GB just yet..

Comment: “Would manually increasing page size and allocating extra memory to WSL2 be a feasible solution?” - No; You need to increase the amount of memory allocated to the WSL instance after installing additional memory. Sounds like you should be using physical hardware based on your memory requirements

Comment: Is the Linux swap being utilized?  On a 16GB Windows system, it should default to 8GB memory (as you seem to be aware) and 4GB swap for the Linux instances.  Could you bump the physical allocated to WSL down a bit and the swap up?  See the `memory` and `swap` settings for [.wslconfig`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#configuration-setting-for-wslconfig) for more details if that would help.